# printing a paragraph using putchar()

Tags: c

Consider the following code:-

```
#include"stdio.h"

void main()
{
  char ch;
  while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
    putchar(ch);
  }
}
```

Whatever input I give to (as a sentence) it is repeated after I hit return key. What should I do if I want to get the entire paragraph at the end ? Can this be done using `putchar()` because `putchar()` can be used only to return a single character.

Comment: what about without using array?

Comment: If you pull it from the stdio buffer you can't "get it all at the end" since you already "got it". Get it ?

Comment: so how can it maintain it in the buffer so that I can retrieve it at the end?

Comment: 1 ) `#include <stdio.h>` 2) `int main(void)` 3) `int ch;`

Answer (score 2):

This won't work, since `EOF` doesn't fit in a  `char`. Note that the proper return type of `getchar()` is `int`. See for instance [this manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar).

If you want to read in a whole line at once, you can use `fgets()` into a character buffer for instance. I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly what you want to achieve, though.

Answer (score 1):

EOF should be used when reading from files as the files end with a special EOF(end of file) character.You need to use any sentinel here to represent end of input.

this program makes a very little sense and I cant picture the use of this anywhere. So rethink about the requirements and change the logic accordingly.

Comment: The EOF could be read from stdin. The `EOF` = `CTRL+D` For linux

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL Didnt knew that. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

may this code help you

```
char *buffer;
    int i = 255;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));

    *buffer = getchar();
    while ( *buffer != '?' )
    {
        buffer++;
        *buffer = getchar();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to store your char into a buffer and the when quit the while loop print the buffer. Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    char *buf = calloc(1,sizeof(char));
    int len;
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        len = strlen(buf);
        buf = realloc(buf, len+1);
        buf[len] = (char) c;
        buf[len + 1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s",buf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get entire paragraph at end, you should store the input in a buffer while EOF reaches. then print content of buffer in a loop. Also as Mr. Unwind's [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084916/printing-a-paragraph-using-putchar/14084991#14084991) says make, `ch` variable a `int`, char is wrong!

```
#include"stdio.h"
#define SIZE 1024

void main()
{
  int buffer[SIZE]
  int ch; 
  int i=0;

  // Read and store in a buffer
  while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
     buffer[i] = ch;
     i++;
  }
  buffer[i] = EOF;

  // now print using putchar(ch);
  i = 0;
  while((ch = buffer[i])  !=EOF)
  {
    putchar(ch);
    i++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

cose all we did in console/terminal - until we dont hit Enter/Return/^J/^M shell not send line to our program

u can get paragraph(more then 1 line) by copy and paste some lines so terminal|console program show 1st u pasted then repeated - output of u program